# Is there a program to create icon resources or all resolutions from vector image for android?

Tags: android, android-resources

I mean for example the app icon. I have a icon in vector format. And now I need to create png images for all kinds of dpi. I don't want to do it by hand. I suppose that there should a program for that, because it's easy to automate this task. But I can't find one.

Comment: There's a 9-patch program in ADT that does that I think. Check your android folder in tools, or search the inner-webs.

Comment: Check : http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent Android Studio v14 does generate raster images for older android versions than lollipop.